# Listar todos os grupos do AD em uma checkedListBox

Tags: c#

Gostaria de saber como listar todos os grupos do AD com o C# forms, e listar em uma checkedListBox, em várias pesquisas que fiz, só achei como listar os grupos de um usuário especifico.

Obs: coloco os dados do meu usuário do AD para fazer a busca.

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Comment: Mostre como está fazendo a consulta.

Comment: Postei o código que eu cheguei mais perto de conseguir.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (userName == "" || password == "")
        {
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain, userName, password);
            DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
            mySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(|(cn=" + userName + ")(sAMAccountName=" + userName + ")))";
            SearchResult result = mySearcher.FindOne();

            foreach (string GroupPath in result.Properties["memberOf"])
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(GroupPath);
                if (GroupPath.Contains(group))
                {

                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException)
        {
        }
        return false;
```